# Keep yAxis labels above xAxis line

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I'm trying to create a chart where only the min and max labels of the y axis are display. These labels are then rotate 90 degrees so they are flat against the line. Both of these have been fairly simple to implement, however I've run into an issue now that I cannot seem to resolve, whereby the bottom label on the axis is extending below the x axis line, and overlapping with the x axis values.

[image: Axis value overlapping]

This is the output that I have right now. The `0km/h` label I want to be pushed up, so that the `0` is in line with the x axis line. Is there any way of doing this without having to create a custom scale?

Comment: Can you add your code or a JSFiddle?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the project has ended now thankfully :)